# Cannot focus on TextInput React Native - Amazon Fire Stick

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a ReactNative app and I have the following code that renders a `TextInput` and a button which submits a request to my API. With my Android TV emulator, I can type input into the text field by first selecting the text input with my mouse and then typing on my keyboard. I can click the "connect" button too and all works as expected. When I installed this app on an Amazon Fire Stick, the `TextInput` was no longer selectable. I could select the "connect" button and could see the ui reflect button clicks on the button, but the TextInput would not focus or launch the on screen keyboard. I was able to get the keyboard to gain focus by setting `autoFocus={true}` on the `<TextInput />` but this results in a less than optimal user experience. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
<>
      <Text styles={styles.text}>Enter your device code.</Text>
                
      <TextInput keyboardType={'number-pad'} style={styles.input} onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.code} />
                
      <Button
        styles={styles.button}
        onPress={(e) => {this.getToken(e)}}
        title="Connect"
        color="green"
        accessibilityLabel="Connect your device"
      />
</>
```

I felt like this article was addressing the same issue as mine but I don't understand what the solution would be for ReactNative (not TypeScript): https://callstack.com/blog/amazon-fire-tv-stick-app-in-react-native/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touchables components can be focused with TV remote, so encapsulating your TextInput in a touchable is a good way, plus you can change the style for a good looking focus effect (onPress or onFocus event)

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            focused: false
        }
    
        this.inputRef = React.createRef()
    }
    
    onFocus(){
        this.setState({focused: true}, () => {
            this.inputRef.current.focus()
        })
    }

    onBlur(){
        this.setState({focused: false}, () => {
            this.inputRef.current.blur()
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.onFocus}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur}
                    style={[styles.wrapper, this.state.focused ? styles.wrapperFocused : null]}>
                        <TextInput ref={this.inputRef} />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to focus it when your component renders at first??

you can try the `autoFocus` property of TextInput for that,
otherwise,

```
const ref = useRef(null);
<TextInput ref={ref}/>
```

You can then focus the InputText by `ref.current.focus()`

Comment: I would like to be able to navigate to the input field with the tv remote, select the input field and then enter input via the on screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**Known issues:**

- `TextInput` components do not work for now (i.e. they cannot receive
  focus automatically, see [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16500#issuecomment-629285638)).
- It is however possible to use a ref to manually trigger
  `inputRef.current.focus().`
- You can wrap your input inside a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component
  and trigger focus in the onFocus event of that touchable. This
  enables opening the keyboard via the arrow keys.
- The keyboard might reset its state after each keypress (this might
  only happen inside the Android TV emulator).
- The content of Modal components cannot receive focus, see [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24448)
  for details.

[Content Copy from React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-tv)